# DES warning message when connecting to Cisco ASA via SSH

Tags: ssh, cisco, putty, rsa

I had to replace a Cisco ASA 5510 that died.

I have everything back up and running however when I connect to the ASA via SSH (through Putty), I receive the following warning message:

> "The first cipher supported by the server is single-DES, which is below the configured warning threshold. Do you want to continue with this connection?"

I have tried to solve this by recreating the security keys with the following two commands

```
crypto key zeroize rsa
crypto key generate rsa noconfirm
```

However nothing has changed. I still receive the warning message when I connect via SSH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issuing the following seems to have resolved the problem. Am I correct is assuiming that I'm now using the more secure key? I never had the "ssh version 2" command running on my ASA 5510 that died on me. Perhaps there was a stronger key originally generated on it using sparks answer?

```
config t
ssh version 2
```

Comment: Specifying version 2 should also do the trick, I forgot that 1 is still supported to be honest.

Answer (score 0):

Does your replacement ASA unit definitely have a 3DES/AES license installed? Sounds like it might not.

Have a look at www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/security/asa/asa80/getting_started/asa5500/quick/guide/DESlic.html and see if that's any use.

(apparently I'm not allowed to post hyperlinks, so I apologise if this suggestion isn't in the most useful format)

Cheers,
jmi

Comment: Good point Jamie, and I should have clairified that yes we do have the 3DES license.